# PHP image width when the image is in a variable

Tags: php, image-processing

I have loaded an image from database to a variable named $image.
How can I get the width of the image while it is stored in the variable?

The $image variable contains the data of the image. When I store the image, I just read it from the temp folder and write it to the database.

---

The accepted answer fulfills this question.
However, I am doing some resizing on the $im variable, so I need to reconvert it to string data, that can be done with the `imagepng` function.

Comment: I think more info is needed, what does $image contain? the path to the image? or the base64 encoded string? or?

Comment: Do you know what format that image is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [imagecreatefromstring](http://www.php.net/manual/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) with [imagesx](http://www.php.net/manual/function.imagesx.php).

Like:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($image);
if ($im !== false) {
    echo imagesx($im);
}
```

Comment: This is good! It works. Can you tell me please how to get back the string from the $im variable?

Comment: In the example `$im` will hold a `resource`. But `$image` (containing the image as string) is unchanged, so you can still use it like before.

Comment: Ok, but with $im I am doing some resizing, this is why I asked it. However the original question wasn't this, so I accept your answer and make an edit with this information, because I found it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you have GD installed, you can just use something like `$size = getimagesize($filename);`

Comment: You can change $filename to whatsoever name variable. Its just an example. As long it contain valid image file, its fine.